# uncrustify: How do I set the maximum line length

Tags: code-formatting, uncrustify

After running uncrustify I want no line to be longer than, say, 80 characters. How do I set the maximum length of a line in the uncrustify config file?

Answer (score 2):

Add a section like this to your config file. It does not guarantee to get all lines below the specified width.

```
#
# Line Splitting options
#

code_width            80            
# Unsigned Number
# Try to limit code width to N number of columns

ls_for_split_full     True  
# { False, True }
# Whether to fully split long 'for' statements at semi-colons.

ls_func_split_full    True
# { False, True }
# Whether to fully split long function protos/calls at commas.

ls_code_width         True
# { False, True }
# Whether to split lines as close to code_width as possible and ignore some groupings.
```

Comment: "It does not guarantee to get all lines below the specified width." In what situations can it not meet that limit? If it cannot, what is its behavior? Also, I am assuming that splitting ```for``` and functions only happens if it exceeds the limit set by ```code_width```, right? If it is not, set, they do nothing? Also, can the way it splits them be configured? I know that varies quite a bit depending on the style adhered to.

Comment: That caveat is from the uncrustify docs. At the time (a year ago), I could not find more info. I did not go the the lengths of reading the uncrustify source code.